# How to read and view Firestore document data using Flutter Forms

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to read cloud firestore document data using flutter form

I tried using the following code but I got this error
Expected a value of type `DocumentSnapshot<Object?>`, but got one of type `String`.

I am using following code send dta to firestore and send to accountnumber(docid) read page

```
import 'package:datetime_picker_formfield/datetime_picker_formfield.dart';
import 'package:kavinie/main.dart';
import 'package:kavinie/model/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:kavinie/other/createbill.dart';
import 'package:kavinie/other/testnew.dart';
//import 'package:kavinie/other/home.dart';

import 'createdbill.dart';
class ReadAdd extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ReadAdd> createState() => _ReadAddState();
}

class _ReadAddState extends State<ReadAdd> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late TextEditingController _controllerAccountnumber;
  late TextEditingController _controlleryear;
  late TextEditingController _controllerlastmonth;
  late TextEditingController _controllermonth ;
  var AccountNumber;
  var Year;
  var Month;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controllerAccountnumber = TextEditingController();
    _controlleryear = TextEditingController();
    _controllerlastmonth = TextEditingController();
    _controllermonth = TextEditingController();
    AccountNumber = _controllerAccountnumber.text;
    Year = _controlleryear.text;
    Month = _controllermonth.text;

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllerAccountnumber.dispose();
    _controlleryear.dispose();
    _controllerlastmonth.dispose();
    _controllermonth.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Create New Bill'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
    ),
    body: Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            controller: _controllerAccountnumber,
            decoration: decoration('Account Number'),
            validator: (text) =>
            text != null && text.isEmpty ? 'Not valid input' : null,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 24),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _controlleryear,
            decoration: decoration('Year'),
            validator: (text) =>
            text != null && text.isEmpty ? 'Not valid input' : null,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 24),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _controllerlastmonth,
            decoration: decoration('Last Month'),
            validator: (text) =>
            text != null && text.isEmpty ? 'Not valid input' : null,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 24),


          const SizedBox(height: 24),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _controllermonth,
            decoration: decoration(' Month'),
            validator: (text) =>
            text != null && text.isEmpty ? 'Not valid input' : null,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 24),



          const SizedBox(height: 24),

          const SizedBox(height: 32),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Create'),
            onPressed: () {
              final isValid = formKey.currentState!.validate();
              if (isValid) {
                final read = Read(

                  AccountNumber: _controllerAccountnumber.text,
                  Month: _controllermonth.text,


                );
              createUser(read);

                final snackBar = SnackBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  content: Text(
                    'Create New Bill ${_controllerAccountnumber.text} Sucessfully!',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                  ),
                );
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) =>editnote( docid: AccountNumber, year:Year, month:Month)
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
  InputDecoration decoration(String label) => InputDecoration(
    labelText: label,
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
  );

  Future createUser(Read read) async {
    final docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('customer').doc(_controllerAccountnumber.text).collection(_controlleryear.text).doc(_controllermonth.text);
    //Read.id = docUser.id;

    final json = read.toJson();
    await docUser.set(json);
  }
}
```

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kavinie/home_screen.dart';

//import 'home.dart';
import 'bill.dart';

class editnote extends StatefulWidget {
 DocumentSnapshot docid;
  var year;
  var month;
  editnote({required this.docid,
           required this.year, required month
  });

  @override
  _editnoteState createState() => _editnoteState(docid: docid, year:year, month:month);
}

class _editnoteState extends State<editnote> {
  DocumentSnapshot docid;
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('customers');
  String displayUnit= 'no signal';
  String displayPrevious = 'no signal';
  String displayName = 'no signal';
  late StreamSubscription _esp32;
  final databse = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  _editnoteState({required this.docid, required year, required month});
  TextEditingController AccountNumber = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController CustomerName = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController LastRead = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController NewRead = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController Unit = TextEditingController();

  void _activateListeners() async {
    _esp32 = databse.child("Py1/User").onValue.listen((event) {
      final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value as dynamic);
      final Object? Units = data['Units'];
      final Object? Total = data['Total'];
      final Object? Usage = data['Usage'];
      final Object? Previous = data['Previous'];
      final Object? Name = data['Name'];

      setState(() {
        displayUnit = ' $Units';
        displayPrevious = '$Previous';
        displayName='$Name';
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _activateListeners();
    AccountNumber = TextEditingController(text: widget.docid.get('AccountNumber'));
    //CustomerName = TextEditingController(text: widget.docid.get('CustomerName'));
    //LastRead = TextEditingController(text: widget.docid.get('LastRead'));
    //NewRead = TextEditingController(text: widget.docid.get('NewRead'));

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();
    final dataRef = databse.child('Py/Users');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title:Text("EBMS"),
        backgroundColor:Colors.pink,
        actions: <Widget>[

          //IconButton
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.undo),
            tooltip: 'Back',
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeExtend()));
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
            tooltip: 'delete',
            onPressed: () {
              widget.docid.reference.delete().whenComplete(() {
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeExtend()));
              });
            },
          ), //Ico
          //IconButton
        ], //<Widget>[]

        elevation: 50.0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
          tooltip: 'Menu Icon',
          onPressed: () async {
            // Navigator.push(context,
            // MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TestHome()));

          },
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 199,
                    height: 185,
                   // child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/img.png')),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 25,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 16),
                color: Color(0xffd9d9d9),
                //padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 131, right: 152, top: 21, bottom: 15, ),
                child: Row(
                  //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [

                    Text(
                      "New Read: " + displayUnit,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        letterSpacing: 1.0,
                        // default is 0.0
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontFamily: "Inter",
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: AccountNumber,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'AccountNumber',

                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: CustomerName,
                  maxLines: null,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'CustomerName',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: LastRead,
                  maxLines: null,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'LastRead',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 238, 37, 119),
                onPressed: () {

                  widget.docid.reference.update({
                    'CustomerName': CustomerName.text,
                    'LastRead': LastRead.text,
                    'NewRead': displayUnit,
                    'Total': displayUnit,
                  });

                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => GeneratedBill(
                        docid: docid,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );

                },
                child: Text(
                  "Create Bill",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 251, 251, 251),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to read the data using the above code

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Where is the code to read the data from Firebase? What is the expected result of this `final dataRef = databse.child('Py/Users');` in Firestore? e.g. what does `dataRef` resolve to?

Answer (score 1):

You have specified the docId constructor as DocumentSnapShot but you are passing a string value of a controller while routing to the next page.

Improvement:

```
class editnote extends StatefulWidget {
  //DocumentSnapshot docid;
  String docid;
  var year;
  var month;
  editnote({required this.docid,
           required this.year, required month
  });

  @override
  _editnoteState createState() => _editnoteState(docid: docid, year:year, month:month);
}
```